# Next app isn't building correctly, unable to identify issue

Tags: git, github, next.js

my [github.io website](https://github.com/BryanMF87/bryanmf87.github.io) is only showing a README file. I understand this means that my next app hasn't built properly and I was following several guides to identify the issue.

1. I have made sure to run `npm run build` before pushing to GitHub.
2. I have made sure to keep gh-pages branch up to date with main branch
3. I have deleted node modules and reinstalled with `npm i`
4. I have restarted computer
5. I have removed both `/.next` & `/.out` from gitIgnore but this has massively increased file sizes for git push so I added them back.

Current error from the latest push is

`git push Enumerating objects: 613, done. Counting objects: 100% (613/613), done. Delta compression using up to 8 threads Compressing objects: 100% (583/583), done. error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400 send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet Writing objects: 100% (606/606), 641.26 MiB | 1.87 MiB/s, done. Total 606 (delta 244), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 fatal: the remote end hung`

Comment: `the remote end hung` - network error?